# Align left dl-horizontal, dt, and dd

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, text-align

I am working inside a panel and am not able to left align or remove the margins for a horizontal list in Bootstrap.

i.e.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">
        <strong>testing</strong>
      </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>term 1</dt>
        <dd>foo</dd>
        <dt>term 2</dt>
        <dd>bar</dd>
      </dl>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/srzyL86g/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved here . https://jsfiddle.net/adityap708/9k0qg8jn/

```
.container dt,.container dd {
  width:auto;
  margin-left:auto;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Add this to your css. Boostrap is giving `dt` and `dd` `width` and `margin` you need to overwrite it.

Comment: Thank you! This does fix it. I'm new to web dev, so wondering why you need the leading .container? I tried overriding the left margin and width with just the dt, dd, and it does not work.

Comment: you have to add `!important` to each property

Comment: because bootstrap has already added styles directly to those tags.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user16666322 My pleasure.